# How to setup unit tests with DejaGnu

Tags: c, unit-testing, gnu, autotools, dejagnu

I'm trying to learn DejaGnu (https://www.gnu.org/software/dejagnu/) and would like to use it as a framework for unit tests for a C API. My build system is based on the Autotools.

In a subdirectory of `./testsuite`, I have a number of C files, each of which includes `dejagnu.h` and uses its procedures to report passes and failures of some tests.

In `./testsuite`, my `Makefile.am` has the line `AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS=dejagnu`, which causes `make check` to call DejaGnu's `runtest`.

What I am missing now is some glue code (probably some Expect files) that lets `runtest` find my C files with the unit tests, executes them and collects the result.

I'm looking for an explanation better than DejaGnu's description in its manual, an example setup or a link to some open source project that actually implements what I have in mind in its build system.

(I am not asking for alternative tools. This is a question especially about DejaGnu.)

Comment: I haven't done this with DejaGnu myself, but my first guess would be that you're overthinking it.  [The usual Automake way](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Tests.html#Tests) to designate test cases is to name them in the value of the `TESTS` variable in `Makefile.am`.  Any that need to be built, first, should also be named in `check_PROGRAMS`, and if needed, you can specifcy sources, build options, *etc*. for them in the same way as for any other target.

Comment: The built-in functionality of Automake (parallel tests) is fine if every C program just contains one test as (without writing further scripts or using TAP) each Automake test in the `TESTS` variable counts as one test case (and not as a collection of tests).

Comment: As I understand it, adding `dejagnu` to `AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS` causes DejaGnu to be used *instead of* the parallel test harness.  But I'm only reading the docs here, having normally gone the other direction, myself.  The Automake manual does contain a few specifics about [how DejaGnu integration works](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/DejaGnu-Tests.html#DejaGnu-Tests).  But it looks like you're right that `TESTS` is in fact not the right hook.

Comment: Elements of the question that constitute requests for off-site resources are off-topic here, but it looks like Google turns up some promising resources with just "dejagnu" and "autotools" for search keywords.  Overall, I see no reason to doubt my initial assessment that no, you don't need to write glue code to connect a DejaGnu test suite to the makefile's 'check' target in an Autotools build system.

Comment: One can use DejaGnu in parallel to Automake's parallel test harness. Just create two subdirs, say `tests` and `testsuite`, which you reference in the top-level Makefile.am. Then put `AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = dejagnu` on in `testsuite/Makefile.am`. The `TESTS` variable continues to work normally in `tests/Makefile.am`.

Comment: Fine, but I'm saying that that does not appear to be the way that DejaGnu integration is *intended* to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Using the pass/fail functions defined in dejagnu.h is only valid for batch tools for unit testing. What you need is a simple xx.exp file like the below:

load_lib dejagnu.exp

host_execute $srcdir/unit-code/unittest